# ReadFile() in C#

Tags: c#

I want to read byte data from external Chip. I am using `Readfile()` function.

```
GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
uint GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000; 
FILE_SHARE_READ = 0x00000001;
FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 0x00000003; 
FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING = 0x20000000; 
ReadHandle, ReadHandle = CreateFile(Devicepath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING);
```

all these constants are defined as public constants. I am getting input report length from

```
HidP_GetCaps. int myPtrToPreparsedData = -1; 
int reportLength = myHIDP_CAPS.InputReportByteLength
```

When ever execution comes to this line, system hangs up and it will go further.

```
(ReadFile(ReadHandle, LBytes, IRBLength, ref BRead, 0))
```

`ReadHandle` is valid, it is +ve number coming from createFile functions and `LBytes =[256],IRBLength=256,ref BRead =0`. Any suggestions why it is hanging up here at this part of code.

Comment: Could you provide a little more code? From where ReadHandle is created until the hang-up. Also, please *copy*, never *retype*.

Comment: ok here is how i get ReadHandle,

Comment: Edit your question.  Don't try and post code in a comment.

Comment: Is it blocking? If it's opened synchronously it will be waiting for LBytes - probably not what you want for a microcontroller xface.

Comment: ok here is how i get ReadHandle,                                              ReadHandle = CreateFile(Devicepath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING); GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;uint GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000; FILE_SHARE_READ = 0x00000001;FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 0x00000003; FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING = 0x20000000; all these constants are defined as public constants. I am getting input report length from HidP_GetCaps.      int myPtrToPreparsedData = -1; int reportLength = myHIDP_CAPS.InputReportByteLength

Comment: Hello Mark,How to know/determine synchronously or not.

Comment: It's possible that this library could help you: [VerySimpleHID](https://bitbucket.org/rstarkov/verysimplehid/wiki/Home) - although it's not suitable for all HID devices.

Comment: Thanks Romkyns. But this will not solve the issue.Any ideas why this ReadFile() when called hangs up the??